# Batch delete all files in a list from a 7zip archive

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I was using WinRar batch command to automatically delete certain files from my archives.

I have a long list of files to delete (each file is specified as a full path to file in zip on a separate line) and WinRar would go recursively through the list and delete them.

The script:

```
rem Removes files in delete.lst from rom.zip
start "" /wait "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" D rom.zip @delete.lst

rem Adds files in Apps to rom.zip
start "" /wait "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" A -ep -ap"system\app\" rom.zip Apps
```

Delete.lst example:

```
system\app\CarHomeGoogle.apk
system\app\CarHomeLauncher.apk
system\app\HtcCarPanel.apk
system\tts\*.*   // deletes all in /system/tts/
```

Recently I switched to 7zip but I wasn't able to find any option how to insert a list of files to 7zip to delete.

How can I achieve the same functionality in 7zip?

```
start "" /wait "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" d rom.zip [somehow add content of: delete.lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this on a sample file.

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("delete.lst") do (
   "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" d "rom.zip" "%%a"
)
pause
```